# JQuery inArray to display the order images are selected

Tags: jquery, arrays

Let me try my best to explain what I am doing here. Then ask how to solve my last piece to this puzzle.

I have a list of images that when clicked, on the image takes the ID from the parent element and adds that id to an array called orders[] and removes the id from the array when clicked again (add/remove from display order). This portion is solved and works just fine.

**Showcase the Display Order from within the Array for each Image Selected**

This is the portion I not getting. I am looking to load and showcase the display order within the label element for each image that is selected based on the positioning with the orders[] array. This portion needs to update continuously as images are being added and removed.

```
var orders = []
$('li').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    if ($(this).hasClass('add')) {
        orders.push(id);
        $(this).removeClass('add');

        //display order by based on positioning in array solution
        $(this).children('label').text($.inArray(id, orders));

    }
    else {
        orders = $.grep(orders, function(value) { return value != id; });
        $(this).addClass('add');
        $(this).children('label').text('');
    }
});

<li id="1" class="add"><img><label></label></li>
<li id="2" class="add"><img><label></label></li>
<li id="3" class="add"><img><label></label></li>
<li id="4" class="add"><img><label></label></li>
<li id="5" class="add"><img><label></label></li>
```

As of now I am using $(this).children('label').text($.inArray(id, orders)); which gives me something pretty close to what I am looking. It just has that one a little problem, when an image is removed from the list, all the labels should reset realign themselves based on the updated array.

Any suggestions, to make this a success?

Comment: I'm a little confused; you're wiring a click event to the `img` but you're using `$(this).attr("id")`, which will return the `id` of the clicked `img` (which will be undefined). Did you mean to bind it to the `li`? Is this your actual code?

Comment: You right, that got mixed with another attempt I am trying to make this work. I changed it to what I had. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You could always lookup all the elements from inside the callback I think, but that doesn't seem to be pretty. Maybe you could use jQuery global events.

You can attach a custom event to your `li` elements like this:

```
$(li).bind('orderChanged', function(){
    // Do your logic here to set the label with the 'order' array
});
```

And then inside your click function:

```
$.event.trigger('orderChanged');
```

I've never had the need to use it and I'm not sure about the performance implications. I got the idea from here http://devlicio.us/blogs/sergio_pereira/archive/2010/02/21/jquery-custom-element-and-global-events.aspx

Hope it helps!